# indexing error, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

keep getting an indexing error " ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression" 
bascially im trying to create a matrix x made of randn(n,1000000) where every jth row is multiplied by matrix NV(i,j).

```
%monte carlo simulation
function [y1,y2,y3,y4]= ed1(SNRL,SNRS,SNRH,n) %ed is the energy detection
g1= SNRL:SNRS:SNRH;
g=10.^(g1/10);
beta=0.8; % is the probability pfa, it cannot be more than 1

pf1=zeros(1,length(g));
pd1=zeros(1,length(g));
pf2=zeros(1,length(g));
pd2=zeros(1,length(g));
x=zeros(n,length(g));
y=zeros(n,length(g));

for i=1 : length(g)



for j=1:n
     NV=(i,j); 
    x(j,:) = randn(n,1000000)*sqrt(NV(i,j)); 
     y(j,:)=randn(n,1000000*(j),:)*sqrt(g(i))+x(j,:); 
end

 %Tgam is the threshold of gamma distribution 
 Tgam = gaminv((1-beta),n/2,(2/n)*(1+g(i))); %probab of flase detection
 pf1(i)= gamcdf(Tgam,n/2,(2/n)*(1+g(i))); %ho
 pd1 (i) = gamcdf(Tgam,n/2,2/n); %h1 % prob of detection

 pf2(i)= length (find(sum(y.^2)/n<Tgam))/1000000;
 pd2 (i) = length (find(sum(x.^2)/n<Tgam))/1000000; 

 y1=pf1; y2=pd1; y3=pf2; y4=pd2;
end
```

Comment: `randn(n,1000000*(j),:)`

Comment: what is g and what do you mean by NV=(i,j);? Some code that can let us reproduce your error would be great.

Comment: hey, i've added the whole code. NV(i,j) is noise varience. but i will add that matrix calculation later, for now i would like it to be a matrix i x j

Comment: @AK4749  i tried that but then it gives me error of : " Undefined function or variable "randn".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three things giving you errors:

1) `NV=(i,j)` This syntax will give you an error message. If you are not getting an error message about this line, you have an error in the line calling this code and should post that too. Try `NV=zeros(length(g),n);` for a temporary fix until you know what NV should be.

2) `randn(n,1000000*(j),:)` is also bad syntax. Do you mean `randn(n,1000000*(j))?`

3) `x(j,:) = randn(1,10000)*sqrt(NV(i,j));`: `x` as written in your code is not the right size unless `g` is magically of length 10000.

Hopefully checking these 3 things will give you an idea of what is giving your specific error message (which is not the same as any of the messages these errors gave me.)

Comment: hey thank you soo much for your help, but once i add in `x(j,:) = randn(1,10000)*sqrt(NV(i,j)); ` it gives an error saying " "randn" previously appeared to be used as a function or command, conflicting with its use here
as the name of a variable.
A possible cause of this error is that you forgot to initialize the
variable, or you have initialized it implicitly using load or eval."